# std::set<std::pair<size_t, std::string> >::find(), without a string copy construction

Tags: c++, stl

I have an std::set of std::pairs, and the second pair is a string. I want to check if a pair exists in the set.

```
std::set< std::pair<size_t, std::string> > set_;

bool exists(size_t x, const std::string& s)
{
    std::set< std::pair<size_t, std::string> >::iterator i = set_.find(std::make_pair(x, s)); // copy of s is constructed by make_pair!
    return i != set_.end();
}
```

I call this function often (yes, very often), so I want to perform this check without making a temporary copy of the string. Is there a way to do this which is as simple and terse as what I have here, but which does not make a temporary copy of the string? Any solution with STL or Boost containers would be nice.

Comment: You're doing it wrong. Write the code that's straight-forward, clean, and works. Then way down the line, when you're done, *profile* your application, and optimize what the results say are slow; not guess.

Comment: There's a lot of advice here that I shouldn't worry about the performance of this function until I have evidence that this function is causing performance problems, and I just want to mention to anyone reading this post that this is marvelously good advice in general. Just not in this particular case.

Comment: Copy a string is not as expensive as you think. Write clean code first optimize latter when you prove it is a choke point.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use pointer to string and override predicate less (see constructor of std::set)

Comment: I think this is probably the best answer. I'm using C++03 (no C++0x r-value reference features, so can't use unique_ptr), and yes, I do want to keep the O(log n) time. This will be messy, but C++ is messy.

Comment: This has the bad side effect of forcing you to manually manage the memory stored in the container. In the original code, as the set goes out of scope the memory held in the strings will automatically be freed by the container, by changing it to hold pointers, the set destructor will not release the strings. This will add complexity and fragility to other parts of the code.

Answer (score 2):

Did profiling actually show that the string copy is a significant problem here?

If so, are you able to change the exists function so it accepts a `pair` instead of the two arguments, and arrange for the string to be constructed directly into the pair instead of separately?

If you can't do that, you could always use a `shared_ptr<std::string>` as the second element of your `pair` and concoct a comparison function that compares strings from addresses rather than value strings.

Comment: @rubenvb:  If `unique_ptr` is available, anyway.  It depends on rvalue references, which are not yet actually in the standard, and isn't implemented in all modern compilers.

Comment: @David: true, but it really is better in simple use cases `;)`

Answer (score 1):

You could always do the find yourself.

```
static pair<size_t, std::string> helper(0,"");
typedef std::set< std::pair<size_t, std::string> >::iterator iterator_type;
helper.first = x;
for (iterator_type i = set_.lower_bound(helper); i != set_.end(); ++i) {
    if (i->first != x)
        return false;
    if (i->second == s)
        return true;
}
return false;
```

Comment: But unlike the built-in find, this does not have `log(n)` look-up times.

Comment: @ltjax: I've edited the answer so that it skips to the portion with the correct size_t part in `log(n)` look-up time. The search within that portion is still linear, though. If there's only a few strings per size_t, this will be not noticeable.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you cannot do that in C++ Standard Library without changing the `key_type` to something reference-like. There are other container libraries that have a template-parametrized find function which allows different lookup-types and comparators (E.g. Boost.Intrusive). Other than that, you can just hope for the optimizer to remove the copy-construction. (Benchmark!)

Answer (score -1):

Write a functor that keeps a reference of the target string:

```
struct match_str : public std::unary_function<bool, std::string>
{
  match_str(const std::string& s) : s_(s) {};
  bool operator()(const std::pair<size_t, std::string>& rhs) const
  {
    return rhs.second == s_;
  }
};
```

Usage:

```
std::set< std::pair<size_t, std::string> >::iterator i = std::find_if( set_.begin(), set_.end(), match_str(s) );
```

Comment: Remove the copy and exchange an `O(log n)` algorithm by an `O(n)` one? I think that'll make things slower, not faster.

Comment: @ltjax:  So?  @James Brock asked for "Any solution" that did not copy strings.  This does that.

Comment: Common-sense! Don't make the algorithm worse in an optimization question ;-)